# Bold citation for specific items only

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have found similar questions to this but none asking for exactly what I'm looking for.

Using BibTeX and natbib, I would like to make citations appear in bold for specific items only.  In the example below, I would like to make "Smith, 2000" or "Smith (2000)" bold wherever they appear, but not the other items.

(Note that, in this instance, I am using `\nobibliography` so it doesn't matter how they would appear in the actual bibliography.)

Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

Cite some papers \citep{jones2000,smith2000,davies2000}.

Cite the papers \citet{jones2000,smith2000,davies2000} again.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\nobibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

Here is my `mybibfile.bib`:

```
@article{Jones2000,
  author = {Jones, A},
  year = {2000},
}

@article{Smith2000,
  author = {Smith, B},
  year = {2000},
}

@article{Davies2000,
  author = {Davies, C},
  year = {2000},
}
```